# OneNote 2013: Keyboard shortcut for exiting a text box

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013

In OneNote 2013, let's say you're currently editing some text in a regular text box/field:

[image]

Now I want to exit this text box and move the cursor somewhere else on the page. Pressing Escape doesn't work, neither do the usual suspects (Ctrl+Enter, Alt+Enter, etc.). Can I exit the box with a keyboard shortcut of some kind?

I have looked at the [official page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-in-OneNote-2013-65dc79fa-de36-4ca0-9a6e-dfe7f3452ff8) for OneNote 2013 keyboard shortcuts to no avail.

Comment: The link you provided says `Go to the next note container. ALT+DOWN ARROW` Isn't it the one you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have another note container to move to, use ALT+DOWN ARROW as suggested in the comments, otherwise just use the DOWN ARROW until it exits from the container (empirically I found that 3 times down gets you out of the container)

source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotetips/2008/10/29/creating-a-new-container-near-another-one/ 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnguin/2010/02/08/a-challenge-with-helping-onenote-users/